# Remove special characters from string except dot - PHP

Tags: php, whitespace, dot

I am using phpseclib SSH command  to delete uploaded file in server. The file names with spaces are difficult to delete. So I am trying to remove spaces for filenames before upload.

I have used `$file_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $filename);` It removes white spaces but special characters also making problem to delete.

So I have used this code to remove special characters `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '.', $filename);`

But this code removes `.` also. `file.zip` becomes `filezip`. I want to remove special characters along with spaces except dot symbol. Pls help

Comment: `but special characters also` ... `\s+` does _not_ remove special characters, only whitespace.

Comment: Yes is there any other way to remove spaces and characters except dot?

Comment: define which characters you think are "special". There is no official definition.

Comment: If this is a filename file(1).zip, i want like file1.zip @ADyson

Comment: try  `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/', '', $filename)`

Comment: @Sreedevi So you want to remove brackets (`(` and `)`) specifically, nothing else?

Comment: `file.zip becomes filezip`...no it doesn't. Demo: https://3v4l.org/FENBW

Comment: However although it removes any other non-alpha characters, it replaces them with dots: https://3v4l.org/uLPSm which probably isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried it with in-built functions but it was not working. After that I have tried some different codes, I hope they will help you. And if not then try to customize it to get the desired result.

````
$filename = 'file(1).zip';


$checking_extension_index = strrpos($filename, '.'); // == it will return extension words after dot which will be extension name
echo '<br> ' . $file_name =  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $filename);
echo 'extension name will be : - ' . $extension_name = substr($filename, $checking_extension_index); // Extracting extension name after dot
echo '<br>' . $full_file_name = $file_name . $extension_name;```
````